# Finding irreducible elements in quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

> Let $S⊂Z$ be  the  set  of  all  integers  $n$ such  that  $gcd(n,10) 
> =  1$.It is a multiplicative set, therefore, we can form the ring of quotients $R=Z[S^-1]$.
>
> Describe the irreducible elements of R.

I'd appreciate help with this. I know that an irreducible element can only be factored such that one of the factors is a unit. Seeing as the elements of $R$ are of the form $a/b$ where $a$ is any integer and $b$ is coprime with $10$. I need to determine which of these elements cannot be factored.

I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $>1$ Or $=1$ ? Otherwise $S= \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ and $R= \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Thanks, it was supposed to be =1. I'll edit.